# Add multiple work items in YouTrack commit message

Tags: version-control, youtrack, time-tracking

With the following commit I can add **YouTrack** work item to the type Development:

```
#DEV-1 work Development 15m
```

How can I add to two multiple work items? I tried the following:

```
#DEV-1 work Development 15m Documentation 15m
#DEV-1 work Development 15m, Documentation 15m
#DEV-1 work Development 15m work Documentation 15m
#DEV-1 work Development 15m, work Documentation 15m
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's neither possible to execute a single command that adds multiple work items nor execute several commands from a single VCS commit message.